# Remember checkbox doesn't work when I close app, should I do anything more?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have tried many times with different ways but the checkbox to remember the login details is still not working. When I close the app and open the app, it's still in the login activity, even though I checked the remember checkbox before, I don't know where I made an error or am missing another step.

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignup);
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    sharedPreferences = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    boolean login = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("ISLOGGEDIN", false);
    if (login == true){
        edtAccount.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("account",""));
        edtPassword.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("password",""));
        checkBoxRemember.setChecked(true);
    }

    edtAccount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAccount);
    edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
    checkBoxRemember = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxRemember);

    db=new Database(this);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String account = edtAccount.getText().toString();
            String password = edtPassword.getText().toString();

            if (account.equals("") || password.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Không được để trống tài khoản và mật khẩu",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Boolean result = db.checkUserNamePassword(account, password);
                if(result==true) {
                    if(checkBoxRemember.isChecked()){
                        editor.putBoolean("ISLOGGEDIN",true);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("account", account);
                        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("account", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                        editor.putString("account", account);
                        editor.putString("password", password);
                        editor.commit();
                        startActivity(intent);
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("account", account);
                        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("account", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                        editor.putString("account", account);
                        editor.putString("password", password);
                        editor.putBoolean("ISLOGGEDIN",true);
                        editor.clear();
                        editor.commit();
                        startActivity(intent);
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Boolean userCheckResult = db.checkUserName(account);
                    if(userCheckResult == true){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "Sai mật khẩu!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        edtPassword.setError("invalid password!");
                    } else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Account does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        edtAccount.setError("Tài khoản không tồn tại!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Or is there a command in the database or elsewhere that affects this?

**Edit**

Once the user logs in, how can I have them log out again? The following doesn't work:

```java
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
builder.setMessage(R.string.logout_message);
builder.setNegativeButton("Đăng xuất", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
       finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: Please don't edit the question to remove the original thing you asked (I changed it back). The site is supposed to be a repository of useful questions and answers, so when you remove the original question you asked it makes it less useful to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are checking for "ISLOGGEDIN" in this SharedPref

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

but saving your values to this one (with a different name)

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("account", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

A few things to change to fix/clean this up:

- Use the same `SharedPreferences` database in both places
- Fix the `if(login)` clause to not use null views and to forward you on to the HomeActivity (as I think you intend)
- Just check if the "account" string is present instead of adding a separate boolean

That would look something like this:

```java
// Just get a single SharedPreferences to use
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("AccountPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

// Don't need a separate bool if you can just check the "account" string
String account = sharedPreferences.getString("account","");

if (!account.isEmpty()) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("account", account);       
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

    // If you don't want to auto-forward to HomeActivity, you could
    // remove the code above and fill in the views here instead. 
    // Just make sure you call findViewById to set them before 
    // this point so they are not null
}
```

and when you save the logged-in state

```java
Boolean loginIsOk = db.checkUserNamePassword(account, password);
if(loginIsOk) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    
    if(checkBoxRemember.isChecked()) {
        editor.putString("account", account);
        editor.putString("password", password);
    } else {
        editor.clear();
    }
    
    editor.apply();
    
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("account", account);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
else {
    // show toasts
}
```

To log out (from some other activity like HomeActivity) you would just clear the shared preferences out and launch the login activity, like this

```java
private void logOut() {
    // Clear the prefs
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("AccountPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs.edit().clear().apply();

    // Use the flags to make sure the
    // user can't press "back" to come back here after logging out
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: thank you sir, but now i can't log out, please help me with the logout function, thank you very much

Comment: What is the intended behavior? The user clicks a "log out" button from HomeActivity that logs them out and returns to the login activity? Or do you want the "remember me" checkbox to just remember the user name and password but not automatically log in?

Comment: When I check the checkbox, it will automatically log in next time, and when I click log out, it will show MainActivity(Login screen)

Comment: that's right sir

Comment: Ok, I added an edit. You just have to clear the shared prefs, then launch the login activity again. You could have your "log out" button call that `logOut()` function.